# Uniqueness of ring product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $A_1,\dots,A_n,B_1,\dots,B_m$ be commutative integral domains.

We assume $A_1\times \cdots A_n\cong B_1\times \cdots \times B_m$.

Now, is  the following correct?

$n=m$ and there is  $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $A_i\cong B_{\sigma(i)}$?

We have no idea this is correct or false, help me thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ though?

Comment: As written you can set $m = 1$ and $B_1 = A_1 \times \dots A_n$. More interesting is to assume that the $A_i, B_i$ have no nontrivial idempotents (equivalently, are not themselves nontrivial direct products). Then the result is true (and you can prove it by looking at the idempotents on each side).

Comment: Sorry, I forget writing that we assume “$A_i, B_j$“ are integral domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true under the slightly weaker assumption that each of the $A_i$ and $B_i$ have no nontrivial idempotents; a commutative ring $R$ satisfying this property is called [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_ring), because it's equivalent to $\text{Spec } R$ being connected in the Zariski topology. Conceptually the idea is that, if we write $R = \prod A_i \cong \prod B_i$, then $\text{Spec } A_i, \text{Spec } B_i$ must be two lists of the connected components of $\text{Spec } R$ (as an affine [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics))), so must be the same up to permutation.

I mention all this by way of motivation; it's possible to give a completely elementary proof in terms of idempotents without knowing any algebraic geometry (although I find it a little unmotivated without the geometric picture), as follows. Let $e = \prod A_i$ be an idempotent. The condition $e^2 = e$ gives that each component of $e$ is either $0$ or $1$, so $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$ has exactly $2^n$ idempotents; this already gives $n = m$.

A nonzero idempotent is *primitive* if it can't be written as the sum of two other nonzero idempotents. The primitive idempotents of $\prod A_i$ are exactly those equal to $1$ in exactly one index and equal to $0$ otherwise, and an isomorphism $\prod A_i \cong \prod B_i$ sends primitive idempotents to primitive idempotents. Given an idempotent $e$ in a commutative ring $R$ we can consider the quotient of $R$ by $1 - e$, which can naturally be identified with $eR$; the quotients corresponding to primitive idempotents in $\prod A_i$ recover each of the factor rings $A_i$, so an isomorphism $\prod A_i \cong \prod B_i$ sends each $A_i$ to some $B_{\sigma(i)}$ as desired.